# Можно ли попросить EF выполнить собственную команду sql

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Есть строка запроса sql для выгрузки результата поиска в файл XMl и последующего его сохранения на диске, можно ли через контекст ef отправить этот запрос на сервер?

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Не нужен вам EF. Что вы упорно к нему цепляетесь? Сделайте обычный запрос с помощью ADO.NET. | Дело в том, что EF требует работы с сущностями, определёнными в вашем контексте. А вы получаете XML, который не является вашим классом.

Comment: Уточните, XML вы получаете прямо в БД (`for xml`) или уже на клиенте будете делать?

Comment: Это вам я писал комментарий про INFORMATION_SCHEMA? Зря вы удалили тот вопрос, теперь на него нельзя сослаться, чтобы другим участникам было понятно, о чём речь.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, for xml, удаленный вопрос восстановил

Answer (score 1):

Да. Если речь идёт о команде, которая не возвращает результатов, его можно отправить, вызывав метод [ExecuteSqlRaw](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-6.0).

```cs
var userSuppliedSearchTerm = ".NET";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("UPDATE Blogs SET Rank = 50 WHERE Name = {0}", userSuppliedSearchTerm);
```

Если же надо получить из базы сущности, это можно сделать так:

```cs
var blogs = context.Blogs
                   .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Это не поможет автору, т. к. он получает XML прямо в базе с помощью `for xml` (во всяком случае так он собирался делать в предыдущем вопросе, который он удалил).

Answer (score 1):

воспользовался данными из статьи: https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level3/3_2.php

Для удобства и репрезентативности, в рамках заданного вопроса, скомпилировал описанный в статье пример в одном файле, надеюсь я понял вас правильно и это вам поможет!

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Image")]
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

    // Ссылка на заказы
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }

    // Ссылка на покупателя
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleContext() : base("MyShop")
    {
        // Указывает EF, что если модель изменилась,
        // нужно воссоздать базу данных с новой структурой
        Database.SetInitializer(
            new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SampleContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        SampleContext Firstcontext = new SampleContext();
        Firstcontext.Customers.Add(new Customer()
        {
            FirstName = "Вася",
            Age = 20
        });

        Firstcontext.SaveChanges();

        // Получить объект ObjectContext из DbContext
        ObjectContext context =
            (new SampleContext() as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

        // Создать объект подключения и команду
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
            @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyShop");

        // Создать запрос
        ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord> Customers =
            context.CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>("SELECT c.FirstName FROM Customers AS c");

        // Отобразить имя первого покупателя в таблице Cusomers
        Console.WriteLine(Customers != null ?
            Customers.First()["FirstName"].ToString()
            : "Таблица пустая");
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Попробовал первый вариант тоже сработало!